# Есть ли смысл использования Redux в Ангуляр приложении?

Tags: angular, redux

На данный момент встаёт вопрос использования Redux  в Ангуляр приложении. Redux - мощный инструмент для разработки (особенно для средних и больших приложений, которое и планируется разрабатывать). Однако, есть большие сомнения на этот счёт. В приложении, о котором идёт речь много иерархических структур (иногда уровней больше 3) и тогда, код с использованием Redux (на данный момент внедряем ngsx) для компоненты будет выглядеть примерно так (код максимально упрощён для отражения только идеи):

```
 export class SomeComponent {

  tableData: TreeTableData = new TreeTableData();
  //build TreeTableData for tree table view
  builder: SomeBuilder;
  public pageSize:number;
  public page:number;

  @Select(SomeState.state) state$: Observable<StateModel>;

  constructor(private store: Store) {
    //...
    //instantiate and configure builder
    //...
    this.state$.subscribe(patientState => {
        this.tableData = this.builder.build(state.items);
        this.restorePaginator();
        this.tableData.isLoading = state.loading;
      });
    this.builder.expandRowCallback = (row, tableData) => {
      ///...
      //dispatch that row is expanded
      ///...
    };
    this.builder.tableConfig.events.rowCollapsed = (row, tableData) => {
      ///...
      //dispatch that row is collapsed
      ///...
    };
  }

  private restorePaginator() {
    if(this.pageSize)
      this.tableData.pageSize = this.pageSize;
    if(this.page)
      this.tableData.page = this.page;
  }

  onPageNumberChanged(page:number) {
    this.page = page;
  }

  onPageSizeChanged(pageSize:number) {
    this.pageSize = pageSize;
  }
}
```

Т.е. для корректного восстановления состояния иерархического вью приходится каждый раз оповещать хранилище об изменении статуса скрытия/раскрытия строки. И это только вопрос раскрытия/скрытия.

Comment: На практике могу сказать что данный подход имеет право на жизнь. Удобно, что само хранилище оповещает об обновлениях, когда это действительно произошло. Собственно привет реактивное программирование. Единственное, что придется к этому привыкнуть и переход на подобное может потребовать времени. Так же советую ознакомится с проектам на подобной архитектуре, так как можно набить шишок, которые потом будет не очень приятно править. Ну и лучше, если такой подход будет там, где обновление в store не будет производится слишком часто.

Comment: @NocteFury, спасибо за ответ. Приложение как раз очень часто будет менять состояние. Хотелось бы узнать, был ли опыт неуспешного использования Redux в ангуляр (и, возможно, последующего отказа) или опыт сознательного отказа от Redux?

Comment: Конкретно отказа не было. Скорее некоторые трудности, которые можно было бы избежать. Например, рано или поздно события будут "летать" по приложению очень хаотично, а некоторые вычисления обрабтываться не тогда, когда это нужно. Но тут скорее проблема не самого подхода, а скорее к тому, как спроектирован проект. В идеале подобные проблемы разрешить на старте и поставить конкретные правила. Так же хотел бы узнать, на сколько "очень часто" будут обновляться данные? Возможно в вашем случае это все еще допустимые рамки.

Comment: Например есть иерархическое вью. При каждом раскрытии/скрытии узла (по сути на любом уровне) - нужно отправлять события. Также будет изменение иерархических данных прямо в тривью (или через делегаты, но не суть), так как нужны редактируемые поля.

Comment: Также есть такая особенность: данные одинакового типа фигурируют в разных компонентах приложения, но эти компоненты независимы, поэтому придётся придумывать сторы для каждой такой компоненты в отдельности. По крайней мере должны быть разные классы action'ов, чтобы диспетчер смог их корректно доставить + разные state's, которые будут всем этим добром распоряжаться. Хотя это можно разрулить абстрактными классами или использовать один state который будет реализовывать методы для принятия action из разных компонент